# $.ajax() post value not reaching php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created an Ajax post request and for some reason the post data is not being received correctly by the PHP script. I get a 500 internal server error followed by "XHR failed loading: POST".

Here is a portion of my javascript:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'newmessage.php',
            // Generic form data
            data: {name: $("#name").val(), message: $("#message").val()},
                success: function(result){
            showMessages();
            }
      });
```

Here is the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Having looked at my code in detail I believe that I did something incorrect in my ajax request. Within my PHP file, if I create a javascript alert to output the $_POST variables, nothing gets printed.

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['name'];
?>

<script language="javascript">
    alert ('<?php echo $x; ?>');
</script>

<?php
?>
```

Comment: `$("#message").val()` is a string?

Comment: How do you `alert` (JS) a php variable? Far as I know, using PHP to write JS code doesn’t work (very well)

Comment: @Sebastien D - yes it's a string or it's just text from the form

Comment: To debug have a try with `data: {name: 'test_name', message: 'test_message'}`

Comment: @StanStrum I added how at the bottom of my question

Comment: @SebastienD   hmmmm that did not work either

Comment: Try testing it instead of the `val`s of HTML elements, use hardcoded strings such as `foo` and `bar`. Then see if the error is on the page or in the backend.

Comment: What if you `echo` the value of `$x` right after assigning it? Does it output anything? What about var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to say how your server is configured, but, just at first glance, it looks like your url may be the issue.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/newmessage.php', // <--- notice the leading slash
    data: {
       name: $('#name').val(),
       message: $('#message').val(),
    },
    success: function(reply) {
       //do stuff... 
    }
 });
```

Check out the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Also, if you're using Chrome you can use the developer tools to see exactly what's going on under the hood. Specifically the Network tab. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Lastly, if you just want to troubleshoot your server, you can take jQuery out of the picture and use an app like Postman. https://www.getpostman.com/apps

Comment: I don't think it's the url... the JS, HTML and PHP files are all in the same folder without any subfolder (for testing purposes). In another part of my code, I was able to load another PHP file without the use of slashes

Answer (score 0):

XHL stands for XMLHttpRequest

Sounds like a there is no servelet (url issue).

or

servlet(php) just aborted your request(csrf token missing)

Solution 1,
    Check the url

**normal call**

```
    URL:"/newmessage.php"  //modification needs here
```

**rest call**

```
    URL:"/http://address/newmessage.php" //keep it in your mind please
```

Solution 2,

```
   <form>
   //...
  <input type="hidden" id="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
   //...
  </form>


function sendDatas(){

var token =$("#token).val();

$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {

jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);

});

$.ajax({

type: 'POST',

url: '/newmessage.php', // <--- notice the leading slash

data: {

   name: $('#name').val(),

   message: $('#message').val(),

},

success: function(reply) {

   //do stuff... 
}

});

 }
```